# Unable to get current date in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift

I am using below code to get current date and formatting it. 
But seeing error "Cannot invoke initiliazer for type "Date" with no arguments"

```
    let currentDateTime = Date()
    // initialize the date formatter and set the style
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    formatter.dateStyle = .long

    // get the date time String from the date object
    formatter.string(from: currentDateTime) // October 8, 2016 at 10:48:53 PM
```

screenshot

[image]

Comment: Where is this code?

Comment: Your project may have defined another class with the name `Date`? This is a common problem for code migrated from Swift 2 as the Apple's version was known as `NSDate` back then.

Comment: calling getCurrentDate() from ViewDidLoad()

Comment: Yes my project had another class of Date. I have fixed it , thanks for the pointer , issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be placing the code in the correct location. Make sure it is inside a function of some kind. You can could even place this inside `viewDidLoad()`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let currentDateTime = Date()
    // initialize the date formatter and set the style
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    formatter.dateStyle = .long

    // get the date time String from the date object
    let mytime = formatter.string(from: currentDateTime) // October 8, 2016 at 10:48:53 PM
    print(mytime) 
 }    

func getcurrentDate() {
    let currentDateTime = Date()
    // initialize the date formatter and set the style
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    formatter.dateStyle = .long

    // get the date time String from the date object
    let mytime = formatter.string(from: currentDateTime) // October 8, 2016 at 10:48:53 PM
    print(mytime)
}
```

Comment: I tried placing inside viewDidLoad , still same issue . Attached screen shot above

Comment: Solved the issue , had another class with name Date.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use this approach to Formatter Style (Swift 3):

```
formatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.full
formatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.long
```

In this case for a date as string with your locale:

```
let currentDate = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "----your locale here----")
formatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.full
let myDate = todayFormatter.string(from: currentDate)
print(myDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
swift 4

==> Getting iOS device current time:-

let hh1 = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date())
let mm1 = Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: Date())
let ss1 = Calendar.current.component(.second, from: Date())

print(hh1, ":", mm1, ":", ss1)

output: ---> 11 : 10: 25
```